# Register a filter in a quarkus rest client

Tags: jax-rs, quarkus, resteasy

Can I register a ClientFilter by using `@RegisterRestClient` annotation ?

Like described in the doc : https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-client#create-the-interface

The only way i found is to register it manually by calling the `client.register(...);` method. But at this level, I do not have access to the client instance right ?

Thanks

Comment: resolved by using @RegisterProvider(MyFilter.class) on the jax-rs interface